# Update or add new object into array in mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node Js so I am having difficulties to update (insert) a new object to 
array.

Here is the schema :

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    ips: [{
        ip: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Ip'
        }
    }]
});
```

I am trying to add new row into ips array like so :

IP schema :

```
var IpSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ip: String,
    objects: [{
        object:{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'object'
        }
    }]
});

var tmpIp = new Ip({
    ip: "5.5.5.5",
    objects:
    [{object:obj._id}]
});

tmpIp.save();

DB.update({name: 'xxxx'},{$push: {ips:{tmpIp}}},{upsert:true},function(err){
        if(err){
                console.log(err);
        }else{
                console.log("Successfully added");
        }
});
```

On execute only `_id` is created (example the 3 row ). In addition to this the created id isn't related to any real `ip` on IPS table.

```
"ips" : [ 
        {
            "ip" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfb5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfbc")
        }, 
        {
            "ip" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfb7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfbb")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d12defd5cc02b810601bb4")
        }
]
```

The result that I am trying to reach is like the first 2 rows:
`ip` - the object id of the created IP object `_id` and not only `_id`

Comment: Show the content of IP collection. Need to check how tmpIp object is formed.

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfb5"),
    "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
    "objects" : [ 
        {
            "object" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfb2"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d12ddf16a6f6fc175fbfb6")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all

The only thing missing was to add the ip (for some reason i didn't ) please see the bold text.

`PhishingDB.update({url: urlReq},{$push: {ips:{**ip**:tmpIp}}},{upsert:true},function(err){
            if(err){
                    console.log(err);
            }else{
                    console.log("Successfully added");
            }
    });`